# Execute :nohlsearch on InsertEnter

Tags: vim

I can do <kbd><C-O></kbd><kbd>:noh</kbd><kbd><CR></kbd> when I'm in insert mode, but it doesn't work when done automatically:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * :nohlsearch
```

This works, but it behaves differently:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * :set nohlsearch
```

To clarify, what I want is to run `:nohlsearch` if I enter insert node, but I still want to keep the ability to do <kbd>/</kbd><kbd><CR></kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to search for another item.

Comment: It doesn't work in autocmds because the highlighting state is saved and resotred when executing autocmds. (According to `:help :noh`). I know of no workarounds. (Other than remapping every key that can enter insert mode which is unreasonable)

Comment: @FDinoff Thanks.. Looks like I'll have to bind it to something and get used to it!

Answer (score 3):

I think, what you want can be accomplished by setting the search register directly:

```
:autocmd InsertEnter * :let let @/=''
```

If you want to restore the highlighting when returning from insert mode, you would need to save and restore the pattern, something like this should do it:

```
:autocmd InsertEnter * :let b:_search=@/|let @/=''
:autocmd InsertLeave * :let @/=get(b:,'_search','')
```

This saves and restores the current search pattern in the buffer local variable b:_search.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a function calling `:nohl` and then `redraw`:

```
function DisableHL()
  nohl
  redraw
endfunction
```

and then `autocmd InsertEnter * :call DisableHL()`

Comment: Why a function? `autocmd InsertEnter * :nohl | redraw` seems to work.

Comment: This doesn't really work. All the highlighting shows back up if you hit enter or exit insert mode.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above, it's not possible to modify outside when being run inside an autocommand.

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a smart-ish way of accomplishing exactly the same effect (at least it does exactly what I want and I seem to want what you asked for).

I have this in my vimrc:
Disable highlighting when entering Insert mode

```
autocmd InsertEnter * set nohlsearch
```

Re-enable highlighting when pressing any of the `nN?/` keys before sending the key, then send the key

```
for s:k in ['n', 'N', '?', '/']
    execute('nnoremap ' . s:k . ' :set hlsearch<cr>' . s:k)
endfor
```

to hide last search's hightlighting
(I like to be able to quickly disable it without entering insert mode)

```
nnoremap <silent> <bs> :set nohlsearch<cr>
```

It basically sets `[no]hlsearch` on the fly as you use the commands.
I also checked, and at least on my setup it doesn't mess if using `nN?/` as normal mode command (for vim's default commands at least) arguments (like `dtN` to delete until next `N`), although this might be a concern if you ever remap any of those keys, or if a plugin does it without you noticing it.